# Is there a way to programmatically distinguish between Internet Explorer and Edge running in IE mode?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, internet-explorer, compatibility

I need to know whether user is running my asp application from IE browser or using Edge browser in IE mode.

Is there a way to programmatically distinguish between Internet Explorer and Edge running in IE mode? Can it be done with JavaScript or vb.net?

Usual checks for window.document.documentMode, navigator.userAgent, navigator.appName don't help here because these values are totally identical whether you are running straight IE or Edge in IE mode.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Given that the whole point of running Edge in IE mode is to get a web page to run as it would in IE, why do you want to do this?

Comment: Hi @user20180413 May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer below? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's impossible to distinguish IE mode from IE11  programmatically so far. According to [this doc](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/the-dual-engine-advantage-of-internet-explorer-mode/ba-p/2542642), you can see this: *IE mode's legacy site compatibility works by using the actual MSHTML engine (also referred to as the “Trident” engine) from IE11 to open those legacy websites and applications*, which means they're using the same engine, or, they're just the same.

However, after IE retirement, IE mode will replace IE11. So I think it may save you some time from doing the detection.